# EA Addin create FlowProperty with Stereotype SysML 1.5::FlowProperty

Tags: add-in, enterprise-architect

I created an EA addin in C# and I want to add a flow property to a **Class** and I have different result if I do it manually from EA. Signal4 is the item added manually, and Signal5 added with API. From Signal5 is missing  FlowPropery  ( from SyML1.5), also that is a Part Property (added picture below)

```
var flowPropertyProprieties = new Dictionary<string, string>
{{"Name", client.Name}, {"Type", "FlowProperty"}, {"Stereotype", "FlowProperty"},
                {"ClassfierID", $"{client.ClassfierID}"}
};

public Element AddFlowPropertyToElement(Element element, Dictionary<string, string> elementProprieties)
{
    var newFlowProperty = element.Elements.AddNew(elementProprieties["Name"], elementProprieties["Type"]);
    newFlowProperty.Stereotype = elementProprieties["Stereotype"];
    newFlowProperty.ClassfierID = Convert.ToInt32(elementProprieties["ClassfierID"]);
    newFlowProperty.Update();

    return element;
}
```

Below are some of the properties using Visual Studio with debug option (process attached), and I don't see any differences.
[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

2.
Also I tried the same API with Type **Part** and Stereotype **FlowProperty**, but the result is not the expected one like Signal4 that was added manually in EA.

```
var flowPropertyProprieties = new Dictionary<string, string>
{{"Name", client.Name}, {"Type", "Part"}, {"Stereotype", "FlowProperty"},
                {"ClassfierID", $"{client.ClassfierID}"}
};
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Seems like the problem is that EA is making a "slot" and not a "part". That is also why it's not showing the "part" properties.

Comment: I know, but I don't know why in the view is so different. Also strange that the name in view is Signal5 / ValuleType1:ValueType1 instead of "Signal5:ValueType1". Also in code behind (debug mode) all the properties are the same between Signal4 and Signal5, also checked the CustomProperties and are the same

Comment: I would check the database. See what the difference is, and then fix it in the code.

Comment: The Classifier and Classifier_guid are the different in DB: Signal4 property type is Boolean (Classifier and Classifier_guid are empty) and Signal5 that I'm creating is a reference type. I deleted the line newFlowProperty.ClassfierID = Convert.ToInt32(elementProprieties["ClassfierID"]); ,  added line PropertyType =Convert.ToInt32(elementProprieties["ClassfierID"]) and now is set ok. Thank you Geert!

Answer (score 2):

Try creating your element using it's fully qualified stereotype:

```
element.Elements.AddNew(elementProprieties["Name"], "SysML1.4::FlowProperty");
```

or

```
element.EmbeddedElements.AddNew(elementProprieties["Name"], "SysML1.4::FlowProperty");
```

And then don't set the type, or the stereotype.
Anyhow, you should **never** set the `Element.Stereotype` field, because that is asking EA to search for a stereotype in all of it's MDG's. If you are lucky, EA will find the correct one, but it might also select a stereotype from another MDG that happens to have the same name.
Instead always use `Element.StereotypeEx` and use the fully qualified stereotype.

There was something weird with the SysML 1.5 and SysML 1.4 profile, so you might need to use

```
element.Elements.AddNew(elementProprieties["Name"], "SysML1.5::FlowProperty");
```

Comment: tried with:  element.Elements.AddNew(elementProprieties["Name"], "SysML1.4::FlowProperty"); and with element.EmbeddedElements.AddNew(elementProprieties["Name"], "SysML1.4::FlowProperty");  and has the same result like in first case from the question:            Name Value Type
FQStereotype "SysML1.4::FlowProperty" System.String
Name "Signal5" System.String
Stereotype "FlowProperty" System.String
Type "Part" System.String
ParentID 23446 System.Int32

Comment: with argument "SysML1.5::FlowProperty" it is not working properly, it is creating a Property with Stereotype "FlowProperty" instead of "Flow Property". Don't know why in code behind is "SysML1.4::FlowProperty" instead of "SysML1.5::FlowProperty". I will attached a picture in the question about MDG technologies from the my EA program